# PHP wildcard redirection script?

Tags: php, redirect

So I just moved my site from /blog to / (root) directory. Now for those people who know previous /blog URL, I want to redirect them to new URL (/).

So I have put this index.php file in /blog dir:

```
<?php
header( 'Location: http://www.abc.com' ) ;
?>
```

and it works. But I want this: When a user visits any blog post from old url like http://abc.com/blog/sample-post then instead of redirecting to abc. com, it should redirect to abc. com/sample-post

I think it may also be done by .htaccess redirection but I dont know htaccess method.

Please give me code for this :)

Comment: "Please give me code for this" - why? What will you ever learn if people simply solve your problems for you? (If you don't *want* to learn, simply hire a developer.)

Comment: i will learn how to do that. and hiring a developer for such small thing?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but this should work in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.abc.com
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Seem to be working. But I have a subdomain blog too (blog.abc.com) so this code is giving Not Found error. Can u edit the code please¿

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$newuri=preg_replace('|\/blog(.*)|', '', $url);
header( 'Location: http://www.abc.com'.$newuri);
?>
```

i think this will works

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ $1
```

This would need to be in the root folder, or applied to the primary Apache configuration (not in .htaccess).

The usual rules about .htaccess redirects apply - including that RewriteEngine on, Options FollowSymLinks, and AllowOverride FileInfo are included somewhere. Full details at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule.